# Visual Studio 2017 and Git Clone

Tags: visual-studio-2017, gitlab

This is driving me crazy. We are using a local installation of gitlab and I'm trying to create a new remote repository from Visual Studio, for a new solution.

If I try creating the solution first, then Git clone, it complains the folder is not empty.

If I empty the folder and clone the repository, works, but then I cannot create the solution because it complains the folder is not empty.

So how the heck I am supposed to create a new clone for a new solution?! The remote repository has only readme.md file in it.

Comment: Alternatively - I am creating the solution with a local git repository. All good, works. How the heck I make the local repository point to remote repository?!

Man, this is so frustrating. TFS is _WAY_ better than this....

Comment: It's frustrating because you want to integrate a Microsoft product to a non Microsoft product. Have you seen this tutorial : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/02/06/create-connect-and-publish-using-visual-studio-with-git/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, seems useful. Meanwhile I _kind_ of solved my issue by creating a new solution, then move it from there, clone the git repository, copy the solution back then pull the readme.md from git then sync the entire thing. But man, there _has_ to be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I found the same workaround (git clone empty repository, copy .git folder to my app folder, then sync).
Lately, I found that it's much simpler:

- open your solution in VS
- select "add to source control" (bottom right corner), then select "git"
- a local .git folder is created, VS also populates .gitignore and .gitattributes, and commits.
- now, you can notice that Team Explorer page shows a "Publish Git Repo" button, press it
- enter an URL pointing to a non-existent git repo, e.g. "https://gitlab.com/full/path/to/myproject.git"
- press "Publish" button

that's all.
Obviously, you must have installed GitLab extension for visual studio, before. 
HTH.